# Get user's email in google cloud run application

Tags: google-cloud-run, identity-aware-proxy, google-cloud-identity-aware-proxy

I have an application which runs on a service in google cloud run.
I use Identity-Aware Proxy (IAP) to ensure that only specific users can login to the app.
I want that part of the application will only be visible to some of the users, and in order to do that I want to know who is the user that is currently trying to run something with the application.
How can I do that?

I tried to do:

```
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
            file,
            scopes=[
                "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",
                "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
                "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
            ],
        )
        auth_req = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
        credentials.refresh(auth_req)
        token = credentials.token
        headers = {
            "Authorization": f"Bearer {token}",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        }
        url = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo"
        response = py_requests.get(url=url, headers=headers).json()
```

The problem is that I'm sending the request to the wrong place (i.e not using the right file).

From what I understand, I want to send a request to the IAP and ask for the user email.

Thank you!

Comment: Your application reads the HTTP Authorization header from the HTTP request and extracts the Bearer token. That token is a JWT that contains the caller's email address.

Comment: Your code fetches the identity information of the access token for the service account that you used in your code. Your code is asking itself "who am I".

Comment: Thank you for the answers! 
I know that I’m currently not taking the information from the right place, I just don’t know where to send the request in order to find out who is the user

Comment: You do not send a request. The HTTP request from the client/user has the Authorization header. Your code must process that header, extract the token, and process the token.

Comment: Do you know what is that header?
 I tried many things, unfortunately unsuccessfully

Comment: As I mentioned in my first comment, the name of the header is `Authorization`. If the header is not present, then the client is not sending one and your Cloud Run instance is public. https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/overview